# XMLHTTP60 Req not showing entire HTML Document

Tags: html, excel, vba, parsing, web-scraping

I am trying to obtain the HTML document from a website to what else, scrape for data!

Unfortunately, I cannot obtain the entire HTML Document associated with the web page. My debug.print statement doesn't show the entire web page as I would like, it gets cut off. I'm somewhat new to programming, help would be greatly appreciated!

My code is below:

```
Const SecForm4 As String = "https://www.secform4.com/significant-buys.htm"

Sub LoadWebPage()

    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    XMLReq.Open "GET", SecForm4, False
    XMLReq.send

    If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Or XMLReq.readyState <> 4 Then
        MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & "-" & XMLReq.statusText
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ParsingHTMLDocument XMLReq.responseText

End Sub

Sub ParsingHTMLDocument(HTMLText As String)

    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = HTMLText
    Debug.Print HTMLText

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works in terms of grabbing the document and the table is present. You are unlikely to be able to print the entire document to the immediate window as it has limitations on [capacity](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5c2a83cf-0596-41a2-9f42-e64cc6b1e556/immediate-window-memory-limitation?forum=accessdev). Instead you could write to a text file and inspect.

Change the filepath ,`"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test.txt"`, to one for you.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim sResponse As String, i As Long, html As New HTMLDocument, hTable As HTMLTable
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.secform4.com/significant-buys.htm", False
        .Send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))
    WriteTxtFile sResponse
    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Set hTable = .getElementById("filing_table")
        MsgBox hTable.localName
    End With
End Sub

 Public Sub WriteTxtFile(ByVal aString As String, Optional ByVal filePath As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test.txt")
    Dim fso As Object, Fileout As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath, True, True)
    Fileout.Write aString
    Fileout.Close
End Sub
```

Reference to HTML Object Library required.

Comment: Thanks, I was just using immediate window. See, I told you I was new!